# Ticket Details are not being displayed (but show up in redux state)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a TicketList that maps over all the tickets in the database. The ID's, Price and Description are displayed in a list. The ID is clickable 
and should redirect you to the ticket showing you the details of the ticket (`TicketDetail` component).
The redirect works - it brings you to the right url and an action (GET_TICKET) is dispatched.

```
            <Link
              className="link"
              to={`/tickets/${ticket.id}`}
              onClick={() => this.getTicket(ticket.id)}
            >
              {ticket.id}
            </Link>
```

The state (Redux) 
is updated, the right ticket shows up

[image: The Redux state]

but my **TicketDetails**
are not being displayed

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { getTicket } from "../../actions/tickets";
import { getUsers } from '../../actions/users'
import { userId } from '../../jwt'
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper'


class TicketDetails extends PureComponent {

    componentWillMount() {
        if (this.props.authenticated) {
            if (this.props.tickets === null) this.props.getTicket();
            if (this.props.users === null) this.props.getUsers()
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { ticket, users } = this.props


        if (ticket === null || users === null) return 'Loading...'
        if (!ticket) return 'Not found'


        return(
            <div>
            <Paper className="outer-paper">
            <h1>Ticket: {ticket.id}</h1> {/* should display authors name */}
            <p>Price: {ticket.price}</p>
            <p>Description: {ticket.description}</p>
            <hr />
          </Paper>
            </div>

          )

    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    console.log('price', state.tickets.price)
    console.log('ticket', state.ticket);
    console.log('id', props.match.params.id);
    return {
        authenticated: state.currentUser !== null,
        userId: state.currentUser && userId(state.currentUser.jwt),
        ticket: state.tickets && state.tickets[props.match.params.id],
        users: state.users,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getTicket,
    getUsers
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TicketDetails)
```

Comment: You say the redirect works, so what is displayed when you click on an id. Is it just a blank page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a boolean value in mapStateToProps

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
    console.log('price', state.tickets.price)
    console.log('ticket', state.ticket);
    console.log('id', props.match.params.id);
    return {
        authenticated: state.currentUser !== null,
        userId: state.currentUser && userId(state.currentUser.jwt),// here also boolean value will be added
        ticket: state.tickets.filter((ticket) => (ticket.id === props.match.params.id)),
        users: state.users,
    }
}
```

Update ***

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
     return {
            getTicket : () => dispatch(getTicket()),
            getUsers : () => dispatch(getUsers())
     }    


};
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?
the jwt in the state should be there 
so the mapping to props should only happen when 'true' right?
Could you give an example on a better way to write this?
I am fairly new to react-redux
so I dont really know how I would refactor this..
as in
getting the data from my redux state back into the component.

Comment: you are doing two kinds of thing with variable ticket.. if (!ticket) return 'Not found' and {ticket.description}. In first case you are using it as boolean and in second case using it as object

Comment: And when you are mapping state to props you are populating your prop state variable with boolean value. so when you are are saving a boolean value how can you can data from it?

Comment: and when you are new do not make things complex using things like this-- const { ticket, users } = this.props

Comment: But by checking if (!ticket) 
isn't that checking if the object is coming in?
by complex things, you mean the destructuring right?
well, in other cases this worked.
so I figured it should work in this case.
So how would you go about, 
fetching the data from the state and render it inside the component?

Comment: oh.. i forgot that was destrucuring.. yes that will work

Comment: since that was a destructure form everything seems fine and rendering is correct

Comment: yes.
I thought so as well.
but nothing is being rendered.

Comment: somehow the data is not called for the proper way.
or its not coming in 
because somehow
even a simple console.log("hello") 
inside the render method 
doesnt show up in the console (dev tools)

Comment: which method you are talking about

Comment: render() {
        console.log('hello')
        const { ticket, users } = this.props

        if (ticket === null || users === null) return 'Loading...'
        if (!ticket) return 'Not found'


        return(
            <div>
            <Paper className="outer-paper">
            <h1>Ticket: {ticket.id}</h1> {/* should display authors name */}
            <p>Price: {ticket.price}</p>
            <p>Description: {ticket.description}</p>
            <hr />
          </Paper>
            </div>

          )

}

Comment: Okay the render method 
now renders
the console.log('hello') 
and shows up in the console when I click on a ticket

Comment: something  was wrong in the routing of the at the parent component.

Comment: still no elements are rendered to the page.